# Slice of (choose one out of finite number of interfaces)

Tags: interface, go, slice

How can I make the `RemoveDead` function accept other slices of interfaces (or maybe even slices of struct pointers) that implement `Liver` with little impact on performance?

It seems to me that the function would have to take an `interface{}` as argument and do runtime conversions, but I'm not sure how to do the conversions. I would also guess that doing `x.(Liver)` is a lot slower than `Liver(x)`, because the latter is a compile time conversion.

Is the best solution to copy-paste the function and change the argument and return type in each copy? Only three or four copies would be needed, but it would still feel like a very clumsy solution.

```
type Updater interface {
    Liver
    Update() bool
}

type Liver interface {
    Alive() bool
}

func RemoveDead(all []Updater) []Updater {
    for i := len(all) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        if Liver(all[i]).Alive() == false {
            all[i] = all[len(all)-1]
            all = all[:len(all)-1]
        }
    }
    return all
}
```

Comment: You may be interested in reading this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163660/call-go-function-that-accepts-a-slice-of-interface-a-with-a-slice-of-struct-b-b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, a slice of type `[]Updater` cannot be turned to a `[]Liver` with a simple type assertion; their type are not interfaces, but slices of interfaces. For the same reason is it not possible to pass a `[]Updater` to a function wanting an `[]interface{}` as parameter.

However, you can do what you desire using the `reflect` package. Reflection is useful but will come at a cost on performance. If you consider the cost to high, then you will probably have to use the copy-paste solution.

The code below can surely be improved, but it shows how to solve the problem with reflection, and it might be useful when making a benchmark. Currently it regards any even U value as Alive:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Updater interface {
    Alive() bool
    Update() bool
}

type Liver interface {
    Alive() bool
}

type U int
func (u U) Alive() bool  { return u % 2 == 0 }

func RemoveDead(all interface{}) interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(all)
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        panic("RemoveDead requires a slice")
    }
    for i := v.Len() - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        l := v.Index(i)
        if l.Interface().(Liver).Alive() == false {
            l.Set(v.Index(v.Len()-1))
            v = v.Slice(0, v.Len()-1)
        }
    }
    return v.Interface()
}

func main() {
    u := []U{1,4,7,2,12}
    fmt.Println("Before: ", u)
    u  = RemoveDead(u).([]U)
    fmt.Println("After: ", u)
}
```

Output:

```
Before:  [1 4 7 2 12]
After:  [2 4 12]
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/wzjAUoDDFI)

Answer (score 0):

You could define third interface:

```
type UpdaterLiver interface {
    Updater
    Liver
}
```

then change definition of `RemoveDead` to be

```
func RemoveDead(all []UpdaterLiver) []UpdaterLiver
```

Comment: That's not actually going to help, since the various slice types are not interchangeable: http://play.golang.org/p/dhlqMjvBjv